# Why do these generate different TikZ graphs?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I tried doing some TikZ automation and got stuck in the following example:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.8, ->, scale  = 1.5] 
    \tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \def \n {4}
    
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
    {
      \node[vertex] (\s)
        at ({int(mod(\s - 1, 2)* 3) } , {int(-int((\s - 1) / 2) * 3))}) {$\s$};
    }
    \foreach[evaluate=\s as \ns using int({mod(\s, \n)+1})] \s in {1,...,\n}
    {
        \draw[] (\s) --  (\ns); 
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

which produces results with node arrows crossing through the labels. I tried doing it manually:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.8, ->, scale  = 1.5] 
        \tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]

        \foreach \name/\x/\y in {1/0/0, 2/1/0, 3/0/-1, 4/1/-1}
        {
            \node[vertex] (\name) at ({\x * 3}, {\y * 3}) {$\name$};
        }

        \foreach \from/\to in {1/2, 2/3, 3/4, 4/1}
        {
            \draw[] (\from) --  (\to);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

and it worked correctly (first is top code, second is bottom).

[image]

Where does the difference come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the curly braces incorrectly. Instead of

```
int({mod(\s, \n)+1})
```

you need

```
{int(mod(\s, \n)+1)}
```

to avoid numbers like `1.0`, where `.0` gets interpreted as the east anchor.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.8, ->, scale  = 1.5,
    vertex/.style={circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt}]
    \def \n {4}
    
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\n}
    {
      \node[vertex] (\s)
        at ({int(mod(\s - 1, 2)* 3) } , {int(-int((\s - 1) / 2) * 3))}) {$\s$};
    }
    \foreach[evaluate=\s as \ns using {int(mod(\s, \n)+1)}] \s in {1,...,\n}
    {
        \draw[] (\s) --  (\ns); 
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow, that was simple enough. Now i also know that I can use numbers for anchors. Thank you very much